# Preventing tab key press to access disabled inputText and focus next enabled input

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsf

I want to make the tab key press to access only the enabled inputext box in jsf.

Ex:

I have a datatable with 5 rows and 4 columns. In that first 2 column are inputtext boxes are editable and 3rd & 4th column text boxes are disabled and readonly. While i'm pressing tab key my curser should focus only the enabled textboxes ie. only first 2 column textboxes should be focused. is there any way to fix this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In JSF inputtext we have a option of tabindex. It's showing the hint as **Position of this element in the tabbing order for the current document. This value must be an integer 
 between 0 and 32767.** But when we are giving `tabindex="-1"` it's preventing the input box from getting focus while `tab key` press.